# Duplicate DAO object functionality

Tags: dao

I'm working on implementing some basic DAO operations, but in my database I have different tables with the exact same structure.

For instance, if I'm configuring a car that has specific options I might have a configuration table with the following fields:

```
Configuration

 - UID id
 - varchar name
 - UID interiorColor
 - UID exteriorColor
```

With each color table looking like this:

```
InteriorColor/ExteriorColor
 - UID id
 - varchar name
 - varchar description
 - int cost
```

If I'm creating representative objects (`Configuration`, `InteriorColor`, etc.) for use with the DAO pattern, would I need to duplicate essentially identical objects for `InteriorColor` and `ExteriorColor`?

I thought of simply writing an abstract class and then extending it as each unique type without overriding any methods, but it just feels odd...

Answer (score 0):

If you have no choice over the tables and you have to go ahead with the current table structure then I would recommend that you can have one Interface Color and one class COLOR that will represent both. Interface will ensure that you are using polymorphism so later you can have the flexibility to sub-class it and add or override the existing behavior, if required.

Comment: I recognize this as an option - but can you make a case as to why one class should represent both interior and exterior color in this case?  Using the same class for both would allow me to assign and exterior color to an interior color and vice versa, thereby breaking my data model.  What would be the reason for providing the means to arrive at an inconsistent data model?

Comment: Genearlly, class diagram doesnt match with Data Model. We have to map the classes from Class diagram to data model. You can still use one class but you have to introduce one type variable which will distinguish what type of objec it is. or you can have two subclasses. you have to see your requiements which one is more appropriate.

Comment: That's the thing - I have very loose requirements.  This question was aimed at best practices and pros/cons of potential approaches.  I was more or less seeking information as to why one approach would be more commonly used over another.